# Maven unit test concurrency and resource limits

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, ant

I am trying to migrate an ant project to maven 3.1. Currently, we have targets for each environment that we want to test against (servers) that run the same set of tests for Chrome and Firefox. Due to several limits, we can't run two browsers of the same type at the same time.  If I setup maven surefire plugin to run 1 test at a time, the results work.  If I test with two threads, eventually they start failing as one browser is executed multiple times due to Firefox performaning slower with our site.

In ant, the test target contains this:

```
<parallel threadCount="2">
        <junit fork="yes" printsummary="withOutAndErr" haltonfailure="no">
            <formatter type="xml" />
            <batchtest fork="true" todir="${junit.output.dir}">
                <fileset dir="target/test-classes/" includes="**/TestFirefox.class">
                </fileset>
            </batchtest>
            <classpath refid="DartSeleniumTest.classpath" />
        </junit>

        <junit fork="yes" printsummary="withOutAndErr" haltonfailure="no">
            <formatter type="xml" />
            <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${junit.output.dir}">
                <fileset dir="target/test-classes/" includes="**/TestChrome.class" />
            </batchtest>
            <classpath  refid="DartSeleniumTest.classpath" />
        </junit>
    </parallel>
```

I've tried using the antrun plugin as an alternative to surefire, but it ships with junit 3.x.  Are there any other options to run tests in parallel but grouped?

Comment: Persumably JUnit 3.x is a problem because your tests are written for JUnit 4.x?

Comment: Yes, we have 400 tests and I'd rather not switch to junit 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK - based on your comment, you'd like to be able to run JUnit 4.x tests with the Maven Antrun plugin, but it has a dependency on JUnit 3.x.

The plugin section in the pom allows you to specify dependencies, which will override those the plugin has by default - it described in [POM Reference - plugins](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugins)

In your case, this means you'll end up with a plugin that looks like this:

```
<plugin>

  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.7</version>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
      <artifactId>ant-junit</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.4</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <executions>

    <execution>

      <id>test</id>
      <phase>test</phase>

      <configuration>
        <target>

          <property name="reports.tests" value="${basedir}/target/ant-test-reports"/>
          <property name="compile.classpath" refid="maven.compile.classpath"/>
          <property name="test.classpath" refid="maven.test.classpath"/>

          <mkdir dir="${reports.tests}"/>

          <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="yes">

            <classpath>
              <pathelement path="${compile.classpath}"/>
              <pathelement path="${test.classpath}"/>
            </classpath>

            <formatter type="plain"/>

            <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${reports.tests}">

              <fileset dir="${basedir}/src/test/java">
                <include name="**/*Test.java"/>
              </fileset>

            </batchtest>

          </junit>

        </target>

      </configuration>

      <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
      </goals>

    </execution>

  </executions>

</plugin>
```

You'll probably want to disable the Surefire plugin to stop it running your tests as well as ANT, which can be done like this:

```
<plugin>

  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.16</version>

  <configuration>
    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
  </configuration>

</plugin>
```

Comment: When I try to run with this solution, I get the following error "the class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask was not found."

Comment: Apologies, I put the wrong dependency in. I just tried the above (with the correct dependencu) with a JUnit 4.x test and it works :-)

Comment: Thank you Nick. I was able to get a junit task to kick off by using an ant build.xml rather than inlining the configuration, but otherwise this is exactly what I needed.